# Persistence with Vaadin

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I'm trying to learn vaadin. I'm really confused how to do any kind of application development with persistence because if I have a reference to my service layer objects, they get stored in session and I really don't want that. Persistence stuff just isn't serializable.

My case is that I have an already made application that uses Spring and I'm creating a new UI for it with Vaadin. I can inject the spring stuff to my Vaadin application but that gets stored in the session. Any tips?

By the way how do you post in the Vaadin forums? I can't find a post button or way to register :)

Comment: You must be registered to be able to post a question on the forums. Click "Join Vaadin" at the top of the page, it takes you to the login screen, then just click on "create account" and sign up. Once you've signed in and are inlogged, go to the forums, select a category. On that page, there is a "Post new thread"-button next to the search box.

Comment: Oh didn't see that Join Vaadin text. It's so small :)

Comment: You could use @Configurable, see my own description here: http://info.michael-simons.eu/2013/03/12/vaadin-spring-using-configurable-in-vaadin-components/ Those Services can be marked transient and are autowired again after deserialisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the Vaadin book covers this issue. The solution they recommend is to use ThreadLocal to store the Service objects. The ThreadLocal is initialised and destroyed in the transactionStart and transactionEnd of the Application class.

More detailed instructions in the Vaadin book: http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.global.html

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions:

- Define your containers as only containing *presentation* data. Don't keep any direct references from your presentation objects to your persistent objects.
- Define a "load" operation that, within a transaction, loads the persistent data objects and converts them into the corresponding presentation objects that back your container.
- Make all your containers read-only (following the model-view-controller pattern: the container is the model)
- Set up notifications/triggers as necessary to reload your containers when the underlying persistent data changes.
- For scalability, design or use containers that know how to lazy load, etc., so you don't populate the entire container at once (note: difficult with `TreeTable` - see [issue #9516](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/9516))

Comment: This is kind of old question and now that I read it again, no wonder I kept getting answers to problems I don't have :) It isn't entirely clear what was my actual problem so here goes:

My problem was the actual "load" operation you were talking about. To load or persist data I had a MyObjectRepository which handled persistance and transactions. To load or persist objects I had to have a reference to this MyObjectRepository in my Vaadin classes. Problem with MyObjectRepository is that it cannot be serialized because it has DB connections and all that other stuff.

Comment: If you're using Spring, try the [Spring Stuff](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/spring-stuff) add-on.

Comment: Hey that seems like an excellent library! I have to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/enterprise-app.
This add-on use spring and hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I use hibernate with Vaadin.  My main application class has a session factory method:

```
    public Session getSession() {
    Session currentSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
            .getCurrentSession();
    if(!currentSession.getTransaction().isActive()) {
        currentSession.beginTransaction();
    }
    return currentSession;
}
```

Every class that needs to persist anything will use a reference to the main app then grab a session.

Then I have a service layer that uses HQL named queries then returns that data as Lists.

```
    public List<DataClass> getEntriesforDate(Date date, Integer key) {
    return mainApp.getSession().getNamedQuery(DataClass.NAMEDQUERY)
            .setParameter("key", key).list();
}
```

For saving you just have a ORM class mapped to a table, you populate an instance of that class then use merge to persist the object:

```
getSession().merge(o);
```

Here is a detailed explanation from the Vaadin Wiki:

[Hibernate with Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using%20Hibernate%20with%20Vaadin?p_r_p_185834411_title=Using%2520Hibernate%2520with%2520Vaadin)

Answer (score -2):

In Vaadin persistence data is not stored in your session, so you do not need to worry about this.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. How is persistence data not stored in session? If Application is stored in session and my application has reference to EntityManager(JPA) or datasource then where are those stored?